# How to calculate the angular frequency of a cosine wave and sine wave added together?

Tags: trigonometry

I'm trying to find a way to calculate the angular frequency of the following wave:

$$3\cos(2t)-2\sin(4t-1)$$

I know how to calculate the angular frequency for a cosine wave or sine wave by taking the coefficient of $t$, does it involve trigonometric identities? How do I go about getting the angular frequency of the sum of a cosine and a sine wave as above?

I plotted it on the graph and I could find it that way but would prefer to find it mathematically.

Any hints would be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: I would like to define angular frequency for a periodic function as $2\pi/T$ where $T$ is the period, but many sources (such as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_frequency) seem to define angular frequency only for pure sinusoidal functions. What definition are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If frequencies are different there exists no common angular frequecy, it cannot be found.

If the frequencies are slightly different however we can have a $beat$ frequency.

Comment: How about t and 2t?

Comment: They are different, no?

Answer (score 0):

$\begin{array}\\
3\cos(2t)-2\sin(4t-1)
&=3\cos(2t)-2(\sin(4t)\cos(1)-\cos(4t)\sin(1))\\
&=3\cos(2t)-2((2\sin(2t)\cos(2t)\cos(1)-(\cos^2(2t)-\sin^2(2t)\sin(1))\\
\end{array}
$